# Are these two representations of $SU(2)$ equivalent?

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Consider $\Lambda^2(\mathbb{C}^n)$. It is a vector space of dimension $n$ choose $2$. On the other hand, consider $Sym^2(\mathbb{C}^{n-1})$. It so happens that this is also a vector space of dimension $n$ choose $2$. And of course there are analogous equalities of dimensions between, say $\Lambda^k(\mathbb{C}^n)$ and $Sym^k(\mathbb{C}^{n-k+1})$. However, this does not seem to be more than an "accidental" isomorphism, so to speak.

However, there may be more to the story, if we assume further structure. Note that $Sym^{n-1}(\mathbb{C}^2)$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space. Is it true that
$$\Lambda^2( Sym^{n-1}(\mathbb{C}^2) ) \simeq Sym^2( Sym^{n-2}(\mathbb{C}^2) )$$
as representationso of $SU(2)$?

I think that a contraction between 2 copies of $\mathbb{C}^2$ using "the" complex symplectic form on $\mathbb{C}^2$ may lead to an isomorphism from the LHS onto the RHS. Is this true please? Are the analogous vector space isomorphisms for $k$ not necessarily equal to $2$ also $SU(2)$ isomorphisms please? I can write them down if someone wishes me to.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It suffices to look at the action of $\mathrm{diag}(t,t^{-1})\in\mathrm{SU}_2$ where $|t|=1$. On $\mathrm{Sym}^{n-1}(\mathbb C^2)$ it acts with eigenvalue $t^{1-n},t^{3-n},\dots,t^{n-1}$, and thus the action on $\wedge^2\mathrm{Sym}^{n-1}(\mathbb C^2)$ is with eigenvalues $t^{i+j}$ for $i<j\in\{1-n,3-n,\dots,n-1\}$.

On the other hand, $\mathrm{diag}(t,t^{-1})$ acts on  $\mathrm{Sym}^{n-2}(\mathbb C^2)$ with eigenvalue $t^{2-n},t^{4-n},\dots,t^{n-2}$, so the eigenvalues of the action on $\mathrm{Sym}^2(\mathrm{Sym}^{n-2}(\mathbb C^2))$ are $t^{i+j}$ for $i\le j\in\{2-n,4-n,\dots,n-2\}$.

It suffices to identify these two multi-sets. The correspondence is as follows: for the eigenvalue $t^{i+j}$ for $i<j\in\{1-n,\dots,n-1\}$, consider the eigenvalue $t^{(i+1)+(j-1)}$ where $i+1\le j-1\in\{2-n,\dots,n-2\}$.

Answer (score 6):

There is not only a proof existence of an isomorphism, but an explicit isomorphism, which my collaborator and I call the Wronskian isomorphism $\wedge^{r}({\rm Sym}^{n+r-1}(\mathbb{C}^2))\rightarrow {\rm Sym}^{r}({\rm Sym}^{n}(\mathbb{C}^2))$.
See section 2.5 of my article with Chipalkatti ["On the Wronskian combinants of binary forms"](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jpaa.2006.08.006) in JPAA 2007.

It is indeed the generalization of the idea of contracting with the invariant symplectic form.

If one dehomogenizes (i.e. go from $\mathbb{P}^1$ to $\mathbb{A}^1$), this corresponds to turning an antisymmetric function $\psi(x_1,\ldots,x_r)$ into a symmetric function by dividing by $V(x_1,\ldots,x_r)$, as Jacobi's bialternant formula for Schur functions.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, this is what I was suspecting indeed, though I did not think about what you wrote in the 2nd paragraph, that is the analogy with Jacobi's bialternant formula, which also makes sense after thinking about it.

Comment: If you have a symmetric function $f(x_1,\ldots,x_r)$ which is a polynomial of degree at most $n$ in each variable you can "multi"homogenize it. Change monomials $x_1^{a_1}\cdots x_r^{a_r}$ into $x_1^{a_1}\cdots x_r^{a_r}y_1^{n-a_1}\cdots y_r^{n-a_r}$ and now you have an element of ${\rm Sym}^r({\rm Sym}^n(\mathbb{C}^2))$. You multiply it by $\prod_{i<j}(x_iy_j-x_jy_i)$, the similarly homogenized Vandermonde, and this is how you build the inverse of the map in my answer.

Comment: I am guessing that going in the other direction is like building up a nonzero multiple of the $r$ by $r$ determinant, thought of as the determinant of a matrix with $r$ columns, each in $Sym^{r-1}(\mathbb{C}^2)$, using the complex symplectic form on $\mathbb{C}^2$ (by just following the symmetry properties) and then contracting using that. I guess this is where the terminology "Wronskian" probably comes from in your work.

Answer (score 3):

By the same method as in @Kenta Suzuki's answer, there are also isomorphisms of representations of $\mathop{\rm SU}(2)$: $\mathop{\rm Sym}^r \mathop{\rm Sym}^n \mathbb{C}^2 \cong \Lambda^r \mathop{\rm Sym}^{n+r-1}\mathbb{C}^2$. These are analogous to the isomorphisms for modular representations of cyclic groups of order $p$ in characteristic $p$, described in Almkvist and Fossum, "Decomposition of exterior and symmetric powers of indecomposable $Z/pZ$-modules in characteristic $p$ and relations to invariants" (Springer Lecture Notes 641).